# Angular2 beta 8 include Typescript definition files from node_modules

Tags: typescript, angular

I have an angular 2 beta 8 project with gulp working.

The problem is when gulp-typescript can't check the types. 
The gulp task is the following:

```
gulp.task('ts', function() {
  gulp.src('app/**/*.ts')
  .pipe(ts({
    target: 'ES6',
    emitDecoratorMetadata: true,
    experimentalDecorators: true
  }))
  .pipe(rename({ extname: '' }))
  .pipe(traceur({
      modules: 'instantiate',
      moduleName: true,
      annotations: true,
      types: true,
      memberVariables: true
  }))
  .pipe(rename({ extname: '' }))
  .pipe(gulp.dest('build'))
})
```

I'm compiling first to ES6, and using traceur after cause typescript show less errors.
I show the shell log:

```
[19:23:37] Using gulpfile ~/front/gulpfile.js
[19:23:37] Starting 'dependencies'...
[19:23:37] Finished 'dependencies' after 15 ms
[19:23:37] Starting 'ts'...
[19:23:37] Finished 'ts' after 5.96 ms
[19:23:37] Starting 'html'...
[19:23:37] Finished 'html' after 1.15 ms
[19:23:37] Starting 'default'...
[19:23:37] Finished 'default' after 3.13 μs
app/app.ts(1,28): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'angular2/platform/browser'.
app/components/component.ts(1,25): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'angular2/core'.
[19:23:39] TypeScript: 2 semantic errors
[19:23:39] TypeScript: emit succeeded (with errors)
```

I'm wondering how can I include typescript definition files.
I've tried to add this files into `gulp.src` like:

```
gulp.src(['app/**/*.ts', 'node_modules/angular2/**/*.d.ts)
```

But shows:Duplicated definition files errors.

I've even tried to add typing options to package.json like:

```
"typings": 'node_modules/angular2/platform/browser.d.ts'
```

But this file has imports that's not detected recursively.

So...Any advise?

The lasts versions of angular include angular2.d.ts but not this. I don't underestand why I should use typescript definition files whether angular is written in typescript.

Is it possible to import angular typescript from node_modules and compile it by typescript compiler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `moduleResoultion: "node"` in the `ts` function in your gulp file.
This will tell the TypeScript compiler to look for definitions in `node_modules/angular2/...`